# NullPointer when grabbing a list from MongoDB and inserting it into an arraylist

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, bukkit

So as of right now I'm trying to retrieve a table from **MongoDB** which contains only 1 value at the moment. So whenever I try to pull that data from Mongo and insert it into an ArrayList or comparator hashmap that contains an ArrayList it outputs a **null pointer** for some odd reason. I'm not exactly sure why it's throwing a **null pointer** **when the table isn't even null itself.**
**Error**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at krimsonlib.account.Account.addMultiplier(Account.java:538) ~[?:?]
    at krimsonlib.account.AccountManager.MongoTOMap(AccountManager.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at krimsonlib.account.AccountManager.makeProfile(AccountManager.java:61) ~[?:?]
    at krimsonlib.core.join(core.java:37) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.8.7-
    ... 14 more
```

This is the comparator method to add a list to an existing list.

Line 538

```
 List<String> multipliers;

//comparator
  public Account(String id, String uuid, String name, String kingdom, String rank, String recruit, String joinDate, String lastOnline, List<String> multipliers, List<String> friends,int favor, int playtime, int crystals, int coins, int networklevel, int networkexp, List<String> achievements, List<String> pets, List<String> gadgets, List<String> particles, List<String> cloaking, List<String> clothing){
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.kingdom = kingdom;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.recruit = recruit;
        this.joinDate = joinDate;
        this.lastOnline = lastOnline;
        this.multipliers = multipliers;
        this.friends = friends;
        this.favor = favor;
        this.playTime = playtime;
        this.crystals = crystals;
        this.coins = coins;
        this.networklevel = networklevel;
        this.networkexp = networkexp;
        this.achievements = achievements;
        this.pets = pets;
        this.gadgets = gadgets;
        this.particles = particles;
        this.cloaking = cloaking;
        this.clothing = clothing;
    }


public void newAccount(){
        UtilMap.account.put(uuid, new Account(getID(), getUUID(), getName(), getKingdom(), getRank(), getRecruit(), getJoinDate(), getLastOnline(), getMultipliers(), getFriends(), getFavor(), getPlayTime(), getCrystals(), getCoins(), getLevel(), getExp(), getAchievements(), getPets(), getGadgets(), getParticles(), getCloaking(), getClothing()));
    }
 public void addMultiplier(List<String> multipliers) {
            this.multipliers.addAll(multipliers); // this is line 538
        }
```

This method pulls all the data from that specific user and inserts it into an comparator

MongoToMap method

```
public static void MongoTOMap(UUID uuid){
    String trim = uuid.toString().replace("-", "");
    String nontrim = uuid.toString();
    Account ac = new Account();
    DBObject r = new BasicDBObject("uuid", nontrim);
    DBObject found = Mongo.users.findOne(r);

    if ( found != null ){
        ac.setID((String) found.get("_id"));
        ac.setUUID((String) found.get("trimuuid"));
        ac.setName((String) found.get("name"));
        ac.setKingdom((String) found.get("Kingdom"));
        ac.setRecruit((String) found.get("recruit"));
        ac.setCrystals((int) found.get("crystals"));
        ac.setCoins((int) found.get("coins"));
        ac.setRank((String) found.get("rank"));
        ac.setFavor((int) found.get("favor"));
        ac.setJoinDate((String) found.get("First_Join_Date"));
        ac.setLastOnline((String) found.get("Last_Join_Date"));
        ac.addPlayTime((int) found.get("Playtime"));
        ac.setLevel((int) found.get("Network_Level"));
        ac.setExp((int) found.get("Network_Exp"));
        ac.addMultiplier((List) found.get("Multipliers"));
        ac.addFriend((List) found.get("friends"));
        ac.addAchievement((List) found.get("achievements"));
        ac.addPet((List) found.get("pets"));
        ac.addGadget((List) found.get("gadgets"));
        ac.addParticle((List) found.get("particles"));
        ac.addCloak((List) found.get("cloaking"));
        ac.addClothes((List) found.get("clothing"));

        ac.newAccount();
        System.out.println("[Mongo]- Converted user `" + UtilMap.account.get(trim).getName() + "` data to Map, Method/MongoTOMap #" + UtilMath.genReceipt());
    } else {
        //this error should NEVER occur
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized `this.multipliers` ? because you adding into it not assigning.

Comment: where do you call addMultiplier() ? Where do you assign any List to this.multipliers?

Comment: @Gavriel it does get assigned through an comparator Updated the thread.

Comment: where is the "List<String> multipliers" passed to Account?

Comment: @Gavriel is it not there? `this.multipliers = multipliers;` if it's not there please do correct me, 
`

Comment: I see you're calling the default constructor: Account ac = new Account(); not the one you posted, that expects the List at the 9th argument. Maybe there's a setMultipliers method in Account???

Comment: @Gavriel Theres no setMultpliers in the Account class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use the "long" constructor of Account:

```
if (found != null) {
    Account ac = new Account(
        (String) found.get("_id"),
        (String) found.get("trimuuid"),
        ... ,
        (List) found.get("Multipliers"),
        ...
    );
    ac.newAccount();
}
```

OR change Account:

```
public void addMultiplier(List<String> multipliers) {
    if (this.multipliers != null) {
        this.multipliers.addAll(multipliers);
    } else {
        this.multipliers = multipliers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable `multipliers`, but you never initialize it.

In that case the variable has a null value except you pass a valid `List<String>` to your `Account` constructor, but your code only uses the default constructor (`new Account()`), so the list stays null.

If your multipliers is a valid list, the only reason for a `NullPointerException` in your given line is, that you pass an invalid (null) list to `addMultiplier`.

To find out the reason for the exception you can either debug your application or add a logging like that:

```
public void addMultiplier(List<String> multipliers) {
    if(this.multipliers == null)
    {
        System.out.println("this.multipliers is not set correctly");
    }
    if(multipliers == null)
    {
        System.out.println("parameter multipliers is not set correctly");
    }
    this.multipliers.addAll(multipliers); 
}
```

EDIT: Oh, I was too slow :)